# React Leaflet - Align Popup on the center of the map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

If I click on a marker I want to pan the map view to the center of the marker. So far this works on my project. Furthermore I want the opened popup to be aligned on the center of the map view.

I thought I could hard-code this with the `leaflet-popup` class like so:

```
.leaflet-popup {
  transform: translate(-40%, 50%) !important;
}
```

But this does not work. The Problem with my code is, that the popup is positioned independently of the map view. But it should be centered according to the current view. I can show you my map setup:

### EDIT

I provided a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-tree-y6rzo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) link to play around. Click On the Marker on the top and you'll see that the popup is not aligned on the center of the screen:

### Map Component

```
const {Map, TileLayer, Marker, GeoJSON} = ReactLeaflet;

function MapOverlay({setSwipeState}) {
    const mapRef = useRef(null);
    const [donationLocations] = useState([
        [48.135125, 11.581981], [58.403, 20.420], [43.300, 40],
        [70.505, -20], [40.505, -80], [-40.505, -10]
    ]);


    function centerMapView(e) {
        const {leafletElement} = mapRef.current;

        if(e) {
            leafletElement.setView(e.popup._latlng); // center view to where popup opens
            // todo: align popup in the middle of the screen
            // Get bounds of map view, divide it by 2 and apply coorditanes to the popup position


        }

    }

    function getMapData() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    donationLocations.map((position, i) =>
                        (
                            <Marker position={position} key={i}>
                                <MarkerPopup/>
                            </Marker>
                        )
                    )
                }
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <Map
            ref={mapRef}
            center={[45.000, 10.000]}
            zoom={3}
            onPopupopen={centerMapView.bind(this)}
            zoomControl={false}
            minZoom={3}
            bounceAtZoomLimits={true}
            maxBoundsViscosity={.95}
            maxBounds={[[-180, -90], [180, 90]]}
        >
            <TileLayer
                noWrap={true}
                attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | &amp;copy <a href="https://apps.mapbox.com/feedback/">Mapbox</a>'
                url={'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=' + process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_KEY}
            />
            {getMapData()}
        </Map>
    )
}
```

### Marker-Popup Component

```
const {Popup} = ReactLeaflet;

export default function MarkerPopup() {

    return (
        <Popup
            autoPan={false} // Important part here
        >
            <Card>
                   ...
            </Card>
        </Popup>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hello. Is [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-volhard-l33um) what you have so far? If that is the case you center the marker on its y axis let's say rather than in the center of the map and the popup looks ok, centered as well. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @kboul I updated my question with a CodeSandBox link. What I want to achieve is a popup perfectly aligned on the center of the map. Greetings Marco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it working. The Solution was to make a modal dialog that is detached from the DOM.

You can see the working code: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-dust-gcmei?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
// Pass open state an setOpen function from the parent
function MarkerPopup({open, setOpen}) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  function handleClose() {
      setOpen(false);
  }

  return (
      <Popup
          autoPan={false}
      >
          <Modal
              className={classes.modal}
              open={open}
              classes={{root: classes.root}}
              onClose={handleClose.bind(this)}
              BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
              BackdropProps={{
                  timeout: 0,
                  invisible: true
              }}
          >
              <Card className={classes.card}>
                  <CardMedia
                      className={classes.media}
                      image="https://material-ui.com/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
                      title="Contemplative Reptile"
                  />
                  <CardContent>
                      <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                          Lizard
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                          Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000 species, ranging
                          across all continents except Antarctica
                      </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                  <CardActions>
                      <Button size="small" color="primary">
                          Details
                      </Button>
                      <Button size="small" color="primary">
                          Donate
                      </Button>
                  </CardActions>
              </Card>
          </Modal>
      </Popup>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function centerMapView(e) {
  const { leafletElement } = mapRef.current;
  if (e) {
    const popupLatlng = e.popup._latlng;
    const zoom = leafletElement.getZoom();
    const point = leafletElement.project(popupLatlng, zoom);
    const newPoint = point.subtract([0, 180]);
    const newLatlng = leafletElement.unproject(newPoint, zoom);
    leafletElement.panTo(newLatlng, { animate: true });
  }
}
```

You can update your `centerMapView` function to the following. This will first convert your `Latlng` value into a `point` value, then modify the value by subtracting a specific amount of pixels ( offset ), finally converting the `point` value back to `Latlng` and call `panTo` with the value.

Comment: All of this code updates the map view container. But what if a marker is for example in the nothern of canada and the popup opens, then the popup is not placed in the middle of the screen. See CodeSandBox link in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be to make a modal popup that is always in the center of the screen.

Display it on the event on('popupopen')

Comment: Okay so add then a marker on this coordinates:     [-84, -99]Sorry but this does not work.

Comment: then just make a modal popup